# How to display the report without applying the input values in the jasperserver for the first time

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have published a report from iReport to jasperServer with cascading parameteres.

I have set default values to cascading parameters.

While running the report in jasperserver it is asking "You must apply input values before the report can be displayed."

Is it possible to display the report first time with the passed default parameter values without applying anything.

Then if i need i will change any value and click the apply button, the value will come respectively.

Please suggest. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to JasperReport server (like `http://localhost/jasperserver/`)
2. Edit the report (`Manage Server` -> `Repository` -> select you report -> click `Edit` button)
3. Open `Controls & Resources` tab
4. Uncheck `Always prompt` option, and give default values in iReport parameters.